# Android Bluetooth Using printers and barcode readers

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wonder if anyone could please help me with a problem I am having. I am rewriting an app I origionaly developed in J2ME using android. The only thing I am having an issue with is bluetooth. The application reads information from a bluetooth barcode reader and sends data to a bluetooth printer.

Before any data is read or written, I scan for all bluetooth devices, allow the user to select a device and store the devices MAC Address.

Lets start with the barcode reader. Device discovery does not find it. Why? even a Nokia device is able to find the reader I am using.

Discovery finds the printer, but when I try print data to it I get an IOException, unable to start discovery service.

Using J2ME I connected to both devices using:

```
bconn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("btspp://" + addr + ":1;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false");
```

With android I am using the following:

```
String addr;

BluetoothAdapter bconn=null;

BluetoothDevice btd;

BluetoothSocket btSocket;

private UUID[] uuidSet;

.
.
.

uuidSet=new UUID[1];

uuidSet[0]=UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

try{
    bconn=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    btd=bconn.getRemoteDevice(addr);
    btSocket=btd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuidSet[0]);
    btSocket.connect();
}

catch(Exception se){

System.out.println("open read Error: " + se);

Log.d("0", "Read Error " + se);

}
```

The error occurs at the btSocket.connect line

After battling for a few hours I decided to set up my printer and scanner to a PC with a bluesoleil usb bluetooth device.

When I tried the app (using hyperterminal) everything works.

Does anyone have any suggestions please.

Regards
Steve